# Nested type assignment in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Long story short, I'm performing an API call, and this is the data that I'm getting back:

```
{
  getUserInfo: {
    country: 'DE',
    email: 'test@example.com',
    id: '123456',
    name: 'Test Person'
  }
}
```

I have defined a type to match that response:

```
type UserInfoResponse = {
  getUserInfo: {
    country: string,
    name: string|undefined,
    email: string,
    id: string,
  } 
}
```

Once I've done the call, I don't need that outer layer with the `getUserInfo` key anymore, so I've defined another type:

```
type PlayerInfo = {
  country: string,
  name: string|undefined,
  email: string,
  id: string,
}
```

I would like to cast the content of the `UserInfoResponse` to `PlayerInfo`:

```
async getUserInfo(): Promise<PlayerInfo> {
  // here all the code that initializes the API client and performs the call
  const data = {
    getUserInfo: {
      country: 'DE',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      id: '123456',
      name: 'Test Person'
    }
  }

  return data.getUserInfo as PlayerInfo // this does not work
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Conversion of type 'UserInfoResponse' to type 'PlayerInfo' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'UserInfoResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'PlayerInfo': country, name, email, id
```

But why? `data.getUserInfo` contains exactly the fields that `PlayerInfo` needs, and `data.getUserInfo` isnt't of the `UserInfoResponse` type, `data` is.
`return data.getUserInfo as PlayerInfo` works, but why do I have to pass through `undefined` at all?

I also tried changing the type to

```
{
  getUserInfo: PlayerInfo
}
```

but this didn't help either.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://tsplay.dev/wgBdMW

Comment: This isn't a [mre], the code here works fine, as you expect it to work.  Please test this exact code  in an IDE and decide whether or not you have no problem at all, or whether you've just failed to demonstrate it.  Good luck!

Comment: you could even have `type PlayerInfo = UserInfoResponse['getUserInfo']` but I agree with the comments above

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 types that are the same though. You can use your other type inside the other object type

```
type PlayerInfo = {
  country: string,
  name: string|undefined,
  email: string,
  id: string,
}

type UserInfoResponse = {
  getUserInfo: PlayerInfo 
}
```

Aside from that your error `Type 'UserInfoResponse' is missing the following properties` implies that your assigning the other base type to this base type which doesn't work because they are not the same type. One has the same type nested in the other. So this means your error is in your get `UserInfoResponse` function.

```
async getUserInfo(): Promise<PlayerInfo> {
  const data = {
    getUserInfo: {
      country: 'DE',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      id: '123456',
      name: 'Test Person'
    }

   return Promise.resolve(data.getUserInfo);
}
```

your const data was a type of `UserInfoResponse`, you need to return the member of that object which is `getUserInfo` which is the correct type of `PlayerInfo`. You also have a promise as a return type and are not returning a promise but the playerInfo object.

Here is a full working example of what you want in TS playground.

[Working Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwJJgGYhgXhgbwFgAoGMmUOMKZATwC4YByAEQFEmAaE8mRAWwCGASwA2jJlETQAAogAeg-gAdRiAHSh%20XHuWEATCQEYATAGYALAFYAbDtLkwSxBIAq02AAUUEcE10AviQkULTKiDCeooK0KOhYuAS6lNR0jNDIwmAA5twOTvwuMBlZ2QA%20VPqIGFmI%20nlkAiLixTSlDTAG6W05eUHEoeEwAKpIaJggAErSyuBIiUQO2YhQo3ETjFEx61gk-SSgkLAYyCD8AMooAG4oMIxr41jTELOQEXiLvMurY-EgjAgdiA9sFiIIILQwMAYBgqMAoMJwDBvg8-gAKACUm1O-GESAAPFtYo8QAA%20JIOZArODIMCRHF4jRU3yiG5ok5nS7IG7IdQo34TDEAbhBxBI-KBmPUUAAFogwGiYGjVNsSXdItFiX8MbhyZ9yIcWRpRCBssrNUDhXsMUA)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an "adapter" function

```js
const userInfoAdapter = (getUserInfo) => {
    const { country, email, id, name } = getUserInfo;

    return {
        country, email, id, name 
        // other necessary assignments, convertions
    } as PlayerInfo;
};
```